# Count grouped values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Again I need some help.

I have a table (for the sake of simplicity) with 3 fields.

```
    code    id      letter
1   2016    Pablo     A
2   2017    Pablo     B
3   2016    Ana       B
4   2017    Pablo     A
5   2018    Ana       A
6   2018    Ana       A
```

I need a query that results in

```
    code    id      letterA   letterB
1   2016    Pablo     1         Null
2   2017    Pablo     1          1
3   2016    Ana      Null        1
4   2018    Ana       2         Null
```

As you can see I count the records for id and grouped by code, if they have different letters for code a new record appears, but if they have both letters on the same code is just one record.

I tried with UNION but what I got is two records (with the same code) with different letters.

Thanks guys,

Edit one:

The query with union

```
select code, id, count(id), 'letter A' letter
from table 
where letter = 'A'
union
select code, id, count(id), 'letter B' letter
from table 
where letter = 'B'
```

I got something like this

```
    code    id      count(id)  letter
1   2016    Pablo     1          A
2   2017    Pablo     1          A
3   2017    Pablo     1          B
4   2016    Ana       1          B
5   2018    Ana       2          A
```

The problem is that I have 2 code 2017 with id Pablo, I would like to have just 1

Comment: "I tried with UNION but ..."  So where's your query???

Comment: Search for `pivot `.

Comment: are there only ever two possibly values?

Comment: @Xedni you mean letters? Yes, but there are multiples id's

Comment: Why do you need the counts in separate columns? If it's a display thing, can you get your app/display layer to handle that? You'll have to bend over backwards to do this in SQL.

Comment: I know, that was how they asked for the report, just wanted to know how far I was from the correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other approach is using `CASE` expression in `SELECT` by grouping rows.

```
select code, 
       id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN letter= 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'letter A' ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN letter= 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'letter B' 
from table 
group by code, id
```

Note: If there are no letters, then it returns 0 instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it. You only need another `GROUP BY` to get the result that you wanted.

Using `PIVOT`

```
select  *
from    tbl t
        pivot
        (
            count(letter)
            for letter in ([A], [B])
        ) p
order by id desc, code
```

Using `Union All`

```
select  code, id, A = sum(A), B = sum(B)
from
(
    select  code, id, A = count(*), B = null
    from    tbl t
    where   letter  = 'A'
    group by code, id
    union all
    select  code, id, A = null, B = count(*)
    from    tbl t
    where   letter  = 'B'
    group by code, id
) d
group by code, id
order by id desc, code
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by executing a dynamic sql query rather than giving values explicitly.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select [code], [id], ' + stuff((
        select distinct ', sum(case [letter] when ' + char(39) + [letter] + char(39) 
        + ' then 1 else 0 end) as [letter' + [letter] + '] '
        from [dbo].[your_table_name]
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 2, ''
);

select @sql += ' from [dbo].[your_table_name] group by [code], [id] order by [id];';

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: I've never seen something like this before